# Actualizar un elemento de SQL a traves de php

Tags: php, sql

Tengo un codigo que se conecta a una base de datos, y esta a su vez muestra informacion de ella, la idea es que con un boton, guarde lo que en un input este puesto.

Les dejo mi codigo:

```
        <?php
    define('DB_SERVER','x.x.x.x');
    define('DB_NAME','db_name');
    define('DB_USER','user');
    define('DB_PASS','pass');

    $conectar11 = mssql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
    $conn11 = mssql_select_db(DB_NAME);


    if( !$conn11 ) {
        echo "No se puede conectar a la Base de Datos.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
    $input = $_POST['fecha'];
    $query_update = "UPDATE EntregasRendir SET Fecha = '$input'  WHERE EntregaRendirCodigo = '001-000001' ";
    $message11 = "Los cambios fueron guardados !";
} else {
    $message11 = "ERROR !";
}
    ?>
```

Me muestra error, disculpen de nuevo, pero soy nuevo en esto.

EDITO:

uso sql server no MYSQL

Comment: disculpa, pero yo no veo en ningún lado donde se procese la query

Comment: Ojo, estás usando código obsoleto ([mira aquí donde se indican tres alternativas](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mssql-connect.php)). Si tienes PHP 7 tu código no funcionará nunca y si tienes una versión anterior de PHP el código podría corregirse para que funcione, pero seguiría siendo obsoleto y peligroso. Para ejecutarlo, tendrías que pasar la instrucción del `UPDATE`  a  `mssql_query`, [como explica el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mssql-query.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te esta faltando la función de PHP que ejecute el UPDATE. Por ahora solo seteaste un string con el update, pero no se ejecuta en ningún lado.

Debería quedarte algo asi:

```
define('DB_SERVER','x.x.x.x');
define('DB_NAME','db_name');
define('DB_USER','user');
define('DB_PASS','pass');

$conectar11 = mssql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
$conn11 = mssql_select_db(DB_NAME);


if( !$conn11 ) {
    echo "No se puede conectar a la Base de Datos.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
    $input = $_POST['fecha'];
    $query_update = "UPDATE EntregasRendir SET Fecha = '$input'  WHERE EntregaRendirCodigo = '001-000001' ";
    mssql_query($query_update); // Este te estaría faltando 
    $message11 = "Los cambios fueron guardados !";
} else {
    $message11 = "ERROR !";
}
```

Por otro lado , si estas accediendo a SQLServer deberías ver las funciones para la misma ya que mssql esta considerada obsoleta.

Tienes funciones destinadas a esa base y las puedes ver aquí http://php.net/manual/es/ref.sqlsrv.php .

También puedes revisar las funciones PDO o las Odbc.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias !